# How to make Spannable or SpannableStringsBuilder serializeble?

Tags: android, serialization, spannablestring

Will it be enough to simply add *implements Serializable * as this is a built-in android class and contains many fields that could be non-Serializable?

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: what do yiu need it for?

Comment: to store it as i dont like the html

Comment: you mean to save it to a file or to pass it to some component like Activity or Service?

Comment: yes, how else can I do this?

Comment: what yes? save it to a file or the other thing?

Comment: you can only write it to a Parcel: `TextUtils#writeToParcel(CharSequence cs, Parcel p, int parcelableFlags)` or simply put in a Bundle: `Bundle#putCharSequence(String key, CharSequence value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.toHtml()` and then send the resulting string, on the other side you just do `Html.fromHtml()` to get the spannable back, this is not perfect but i think its the best option you have (unless you want to implement your own markup code)

Comment: thats not sufficiant. It didnt even Html.toHtml() the very basic ones like bold or italic. And I want to use the unsupported tags too

Comment: then, as i said, the only option you have is to dump to your own markup language

Comment: why not saving the whole object using serializing

Comment: because its not serializable, and implementing serialization means exactly what i said, find a way to represent the object in a string, so your own markup